# Could anyone explain this line of python code? 'positions = [s.index(x)+1 for x in s]'

Tags: python

I have ruthlessly searched the internet. I know there will be an answer somewhere . However I cant find it. Below is code ( in a nutshell, my code changes a stored array into numbers then saves it as a text file ).Line 3 is the code I cannot comprehend.

```
sentence = "ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY" #Stores these words in the array
s = sentence.split() #splits the variable 'sentence' into seperate words and stores them into the variable 's'
positions = [s.index(x)+1 for x in s]
print(sentence) #prints the variable 'sentence'
print(positions) #prints the variable 'positions'

sentence=str(sentence) #converts the variable 'sentence' into a string
positions=str(positions) #converts the variable 'positons' into a string

inputFile=open("thelist.txt","w") #
inputFile.write(sentence)
inputFile.write("\n")
inputFile.write(positions) 
inputFile.close()
```

The line I cannot understand is 'positions = [s.index(x)+1 for x in s]' can someone please explain it?

Comment: It seems [this is a homework question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37275889/python-controlled-assessment-task-2).

Answer (score 3):

It is a list comprehension, equivalent to

```
positions = []

for x in s:
    positions.append(s.index(x)+1)
```

`s.index()` returns the position of word `x` in your list of words `s`.

Note that multiple occurrences of the same word will all point to the first index of that word. e.g. the second occurrence of `"ASK"` will still point to `1`.

Comment: How is that different from `range(1, len(s) + 1)`? Maybe the OP intention was precisely to detect the duplicates.

Comment: Thank you! This has really helped!!

Answer (score 0):

Hi – translated to Human, it means put the position (+1) of each word of the sentence in the `positions` array.

**`positions =`** let positions be:
 
**`[s.index(x)`** index of `x` in `s`, or `sentence.split()`

**`+1`** add one to the index, as indices start from 0 in most languages
 
**`for x in s]`** and do this for all the elements in `s`.

The code would look nicer if it looked something like:

`splitsentence = sentence.split()`
`positions = splitsentence.index(word)+1 for word in splitsentence`.

Longer, but readable.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and incorporate this into my code.

Comment: Try to make your variable names as descriptive as possible. This helps a lot, and is crucial when your code gets bigger.